# Ubuntu 18.04 LAN driver and some software suddenly went missing without any reason

Tags: 18.04

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3, this one I installed last November and never have any problem so far.

Just around an hour ago after I restart my PC to clear some GPU memory, I found Google Chrome missing, I install that from .deb file and then then found out that the LAN menu went missing as well and I have to use wifi shered from phone now.

I didn't even run a single sudo in that session, just run some Python and Dota in steam. The only thing that not normal is that Tensorflow raise core dumped more often but I fixed it according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893755/tensorflow-set-cuda-visible-devices-within-jupyter/37901914#37901914), so I don't think this is related.

Later I found out that Redshift and VSCode are missing as well, from both terminal and launcher, don't know if there's anything else though. Checked it later and found out that VLC is gone too and got unmet dependencies so I can't re-install it.

The software's' setting are all safe and sound.

What's went wrong here exactly and also, how to bring the LAN back? Also some other softwares that suddenly have unmet dependencies.

My LAN works fine when I switch to Windows 10 though.

Software&Update somehow looks like this. I can only thick the Continue... but cannot Apply Changes, cannot thick anything else either.
[image]

I got this when run `sudo lshw -c network`

```
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 00
       serial: 70:85:c2:43:aa:f3
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.2-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:123 memory:df300000-df31ffff
```

The word `DISABLED` is gone once I run `sudo ip link set dev enp0s31f6 up` but nothing else happens. The network menu still not show up and it goes back to `DISABLED` after I restart.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341690/ethernet-network-disabled) doesn't work neither does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039233/no-wired-connection-wired-unmanaged-ubuntu-18-04) nor [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945561/intel-ethernet-drivers-for-ubuntu-17-04).

Got this after run `sudo smartctl --all /dev/nvme0n1`

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-5.0.0-37-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Samsung SSD 960 EVO 250GB
Serial Number:                      S3ESNX0J827730H
Firmware Version:                   2B7QCXE7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 250,059,350,016 [250 GB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      2
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          250,059,350,016 [250 GB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            118,155,931,648 [118 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Local Time is:                      Mon Jan 20 21:21:19 2020 +07
Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0007):   Security Format Frmw_DL
Optional NVM Commands (0x001f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     77 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     79 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     6.04W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     5.09W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     4.08W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0400W       -        -    3  3  3  3      210    1500
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2200    6000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02, NSID 0x1)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        44 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    8%
Data Units Read:                    18,188,664 [9.31 TB]
Data Units Written:                 35,014,889 [17.9 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 298,357,165
Host Write Commands:                120,009,033
Controller Busy Time:               1,622
Power Cycles:                       1,580
Power On Hours:                     1,126
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   73
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      1,388
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               44 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               51 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 64 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS
  0       1388     0  0x00a0  0x4212  0x028            0     -     -
  1       1387     0  0x0020  0x4004  0x02c            0     0     -
  2       1386     0  0x001f  0x4004  0x02c            0     0     -
  3       1385     0  0x0002  0x4004  0x028            0     0     -
  4       1384     0  0x0020  0x4004  0x02c            0     0     -
  5       1383     0  0x001f  0x4004  0x02c            0     0     -
  6       1382     0  0x0002  0x4004  0x028            0     0     -
  7       1381     0  0x009a  0x4212  0x028            0     -     -
  8       1380     0  0x0020  0x4004  0x02c            0     0     -
  9       1379     0  0x001f  0x4004  0x02c            0     0     -
 10       1378     0  0x0002  0x4004  0x028            0     0     -
 11       1377     0  0x009e  0x4212  0x028            0     -     -
 12       1376     0  0x0020  0x4004  0x02c            0     0     -
 13       1375     0  0x001f  0x4004  0x02c            0     0     -
 14       1374     0  0x0002  0x4004  0x028            0     0     -
 15       1373     0  0x00ae  0x4212  0x028            0     -     -
... (48 entries not shown)
```

Comment: what do you mean your LAN doesn't work? Can you ping things? Is it a file share not working? Can't reach the internet? can reach the internet but not computers on the local network? There isn't enough information to help yet

Comment: In the top-left corner, there should be a menu to disconnect or setting the LAN above the wifi. But it disappeared. I tried unplug the cable but it still not appears. I then switch to Win10, everything is OK there.

Comment: Actually it's top-right corner.

Comment: If you use the Activities window to search for 'network', you should be able to get to the settings menu

Comment: It can't be that easy right? There's only VPN setting there and nothing else.

Comment: Maybe a hardware problem. check drive/drives with smartmontools, also make memtest. files can not vanish in to the thin air.

Comment: Added `sudo smartctl --all /dev/nvme0n1` result. I don't know I use it right though.

Comment: Having you tried updating your kernel or rolling back to a previous kernel version? Not sure about the missing software, but many times different kernel versions allow incompatibilities between drivers and networking. (I suggest this because you mentioned rebooting, which may have prompted the system to upgrade the kernel).

Comment: Another option is, have you checked your system memory? I has happened to me before having installed a certain software which caused my partition memory to be full; and whilst before rebooting all was fine, after it, some software started glitching. This will also happen if you somehow stop the computer mid-updating or upgrading.

Comment: I have 120GB left on system partition.

Comment: Never try roll back kernel version, I'll try it tomorrow. But it still 18.04.3 and I didn't run any `sudo` let alone `apt-get` that day, can Ubuntu really upgrade itself? If so, how to turn this off?

Comment: Normally, the kernel shouldn't update itself on its own [DO Ubuntu kernel updates happen automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819766/do-ubuntu-kernel-updates-happen-automatically). It basically updates if you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` or if you accept a system pop up prompt.
As you said you didn't do this, maybe that's not the issue. 
Anyways, if you don't want to be installing new kernels, you may go on "advanced options on ubuntu" in the grub menu, select a different kernel from the listing, and check if your current issues still persist in that one.

Comment: Well the current issue is that I have no idea how to bring the LAN driver back, as reinstall and all the method I found didn't work.

Comment: did you make a long test before?  `sudo smartctl -t long  /dev/nvme0n1`  I see 73 Unsafe Shutdowns.  Can corrupt filesystem. Can your boot in previous kernel? https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version

Comment: It looks like you unknowingly did installation or installation operation which removes lots of packages.